# Is it possible to hold rejected messages in a queue?

Tags: postfix

I have a custom Postgresql backend for my virtual tables in Postfix, but there are times when a user's email isn't correctly configured and is responded to with a `User unknown in virtual alias table` error. I would like to be able to hold such messages in a queue for review and possibly sending to the correctly configured email later. Is it possible to configure Postfix to send these rejected emails to a queue?

Edit: The best solution I've found is to use `defer_if_reject` in `main.cf`, but if I only wanted to `defer_if_reject` when the email address isn't found in the virtual email addresses table, then how could I accomplish this? And would it be possible to forward only this kind of message to a separate queue rather than the generic `deferred` queue?

Comment: Write a policy daemon that returns something like "REDIRECT hold@example.com" if it can't find the recipient's address in PostgreSQL, and add a transport entry that return HOLD for hold@example.com. Make sure that rewriting is done before reject_unlisted_recipient gets invoked. And be aware that a  REDIRECT affects the whole message.
EDIT: You might be able to return HOLD from within the policy daemon without going through the rewrite steps.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I wouldn't know how to write a policy daemon, since I've never done it.

Answer (score 2):

If you OK with `defer_if_reject` solution then you can add this rule on smtpd_recipient_restriction

```
defer_if_reject reject_unlisted_recipient
```

For more info checks the [official documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient)

---

For **HOLD** solution, you can search postgresql query to return value HOLD if account doesn't exist in table.  Quick googling reveals that Postgre have feature `WHERE NOT EXISTS` ([check this page](http://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/exists.php)  for some examples). (Sorry I don't familiar with Postgre :))

So, in smtpd_recipient_restriction define

```
check_recipient_access pgsql:/path/to/pgsql/config
```

For the content of `/path/to/pgsql/config`, please consult this [man page](http://www.postfix.org/pgsql_table.5.html)