# Are rejection messages stored anywhere on a postfix server?

Tags: postfix, email-server

I am working, with very limited experience, to recover messages that were sent to an address on a postfix email server that had been forwarded to a bad address. So the messages were rejected, but were attached to the rejection notice. A sample rejection notice is below.

What I'm hoping is that the rejection messages might be stored somewhere on the server, so that I could retrieve them and get the attached messages. Seems unlikely, but what the heck.

Also, there is no postmaster alias setup on this server. I'm guessing the thing to have done would have been to setup so that things like this go to a postmaster account, but I'm just coming in to something I know nothing about.

> This is the mail system at host daisy.example.com.
>
> I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
>   be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.
>
> For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.
>
> If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
>   delete your own text from the attached returned message.
>
> ```
>               The mail system
> ```
>
> (expanded from ): host
>      logjam.mail.protection.example.com[192.0.2.10] said: 550 5.4.1
>      [metzger@logjam.example.com]: Recipient address rejected: Access >denied
>      (in reply to RCPT TO command)
>
> Final-Recipient: rfc822; metzger@logjam.example.com
>   Original-Recipient: rfc822;metzger@example.org
>   Action: failed
>   Status: 5.4.1
>   Remote-MTA: dns; logjam.mail.protection.example.com
>   Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.4.1 [metzger@logjam.example.com]: Recipient
>      address rejected: Access denied

Comment: What do your logs say about where these messages were sent to?

Answer (score 4):

In a typical postfix configuration, they are not saved, but it is possible. See for example: [Is it possible to hold rejected messages in a queue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/567344/is-it-possible-to-hold-rejected-messages-in-a-queue)

See if you have `defer_if_reject` set to true in `main.cf`.

Since recipient checking happens early, it's unlikely any content filters would save the messages either (but see `smtpd_milters`, `smtpd_proxy_*` in your `main.cf`).